# How to implement on C# coded ui multiples DataSources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I need help to add two files in as data sources in visual studio 2013

at this point my code looks like this:

```
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
   "C:\\credible\\CodedUI\\CredibleTestProject\\Assets\\domains.csv",
   "domains#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("domains.csv"),TestMethod]
```

but when I try to add another data source I receive errors

can someone help me with the syntaxis

Comment: What type of errors are you getting..? also can you do that dynamically in codebehind vs UI

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have more than one Data Source for a Test Method. However, you can read and use the other `datasource CSV` file inside your test method. Read the `CSV` file using `StreamReader` to get each line and use that data.